# Python: Store variable in function and restart time on condition

Tags: python, time, streamlit

This may be simpler than I think it is, but I would like to store a token or like a string for about 24 hours, and after 24 hours later, I would like that stored token or stored string to expire or have no value.

```
# Function I currently have, it does not store the token and does not expire after 24 hours
import streamlit as st
def check_token(token_provided):
   strip_words = "ab 1jd9k1la0 "
   no_token = ""
   if strip_words in token_provided:
      new_token = token_provided.replace(strip_words,"")
   else:
      new_token = token_provided
   token = new_token
   return token
```

Also, after the token is stored, how would I check if the user inputted the correct token value.

I am currently using streamlit and I was not sure if this is possible with Session.state.

Comment: You need to use a sort of caching mechanism, either use some caching framework like Redis or you'll need to keep your script running in a 'infinite' state just to keep the value of the variables in the memory indefinitely (I don't recommend this approach though).

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I will take a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Streamlit provides a cache decorator having a `ttl` argument:

> ttl (float or None) – The maximum number of seconds to keep an entry in the cache, or None if cache entries should not expire. The default is None.

https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=cache#streamlit.cache